# Скрипт для формы html

Tags: javascript

Помогите написать скрипт, который бы после нажатия кнопки заказать работу выводил бы в новом окне информацию о заказчике, внесенную в форму HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ru" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Имя Фамилия</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .style1 {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .style2 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .style3 {
        text-align: left;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post">
    <div class="style3">
    <label id="Label2"></label>
    <label id="Label1"><span class="style2"><strong>
        Заказ работы</strong></span> <br />
        Имя
        <input name="Text1" type="text" style="width: 107px" class="style1" /><br />
        Фамилия <input name="Text2" type="text" /><br />
        Отчество <input name="Text3" type="text" style="width: 105px" /><br />
        <span lang="en-us">E-mail </span>
        <input name="Text4" type="text" style="width: 107px" /><br />
        Тел. <input name="Text5" type="text" style="width: 107px" /><br />
        Предмет <input name="Text9" type="text" /><br />
        Тема реферата <input name="Text6" type="text" /><br />
        Объем <input name="Text7" type="text" /><br />
        Срок <input name="Text8" type="text" /><br />
        Методический материал <input name="File1" type="file" /><br />
        Комментарии <br />
        <textarea name="TextArea1" style="height: 121px; width: 274px"></textarea><br />
        <br />
        <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Заказать работу " style="width: 138px; height: 39px"onclick="kozyrchuk@inbox.ru"/></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

На странице html исправить

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
```

В form.php написать в таком духе

```
<?= $_POST['Text1'] ?>

<?= $_POST['Text2'] ?>
```